# How to write a c# code in Cordova? for finding geolocation

Tags: c#, cordova, mobile

i am trying to create a mobile based project where i have a css and js files.i am new to cordova and i need to write a c# coding for finding geolocation .. can anyone explain with an example or a tutorial site

NOTE: i shouldn't use any plugin it should be purely a C# coding

thanks in advance

Comment: `NOTE: i shouldn't use any plugin it should be purely a C# coding` Why is a plugin not acceptable?

Comment: thats what my requirement is.. my coding should be in native

Answer (score 0):

Cordova is a framework that allows you to build mobile apps with **HTML, CSS & JS**.

If you are using Cordova to build your app then you need to use a JavaScript plugin such as https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-geolocation/

Maybe https://www.xamarin.com/ might be a better option for you to build your app with as you can use C# instead of JavaScript.

Here is some info on geo location with Xamarin:
https://blog.xamarin.com/geolocation-for-ios-android-and-windows-made-easy/

Comment: does that means we cant use c# coding in cordova?? i thought we can use our native code in cordova

Comment: Did you read my answer above? Maybe viewing the Visual Studio website might be able to give you some more information / tutorials about how to use Cordova: https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/cordova/